# Count the number of times a letter is in a text box in visual basic using a combo drop down box

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Having a difficult time with this one, can't seem to get it right.  I have some text in a text box.  I then used a combo drop box to select a letter that may appear in the text field.  I then need to display the number of times that letter selected appears in the textbox.  Listed below is my code that I am getting a few error with.  The big error that I am getting is

"Index and length must refer to a location within the string. Parameter name: length"

I think it has to do with the substring feature.  I think it has to do something with the length of characters in the text box.  Any help to get this working correctly is much appreciated,

```
 Private Sub cboSelectText_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles cboSelectText.SelectedIndexChanged


        'value to find
        Dim strLetterToFind As String

        'String to search
        Dim strStringToSearch As String = txtWordsToScan.Text

        'Current Character
        Dim chrCurrentCharacter As Char

        'Length of text
        Dim intLengthOfText As Integer
        intLengthOfText = strStringToSearch.Length

        'Letter totals
        'Dim intLoopCounter As Integer

        'Count for the display
        Dim intLetterA, intLetterE, intLetterI, intLetterO, intLetterU, intLetterCH, intWords As Integer


        Select Case cboSelectText.SelectedIndex
            Case 1
                strLetterToFind = "A"
            Case 2
                strLetterToFind = "E"
            Case 3
                strLetterToFind = "I"
            Case 4
                strLetterToFind = "O"
            Case 5
                strLetterToFind = "U"
            Case 6
                strLetterToFind = "CH"
            Case 7
                strLetterToFind = " "
            Case Else
                strLetterToFind = String.Empty

        End Select

        For intLoopCounter As Integer = 0 To intLengthOfText
            If chrCurrentCharacter = strStringToSearch.Substring(intLoopCounter, 1).ToUpper Then
                If strLetterToFind = "A" Then
                    intLetterA += 1
                    lblANumberTotal.Text = CStr(intLetterA)
                ElseIf chrCurrentCharacter = "E" Then
                    intLetterE += 1
                    lblENumberTotal.Text = CStr(intLetterE)
                ElseIf chrCurrentCharacter = "I" Then
                    intLetterI += 1
                    lblINumberTotal.Text = CStr(intLetterI)
                ElseIf chrCurrentCharacter = "O" Then
                    intLetterO += 1
                    lblONumberTotal.Text = CStr(intLetterO)
                ElseIf chrCurrentCharacter = "U" Then
                    intLetterU += 1
                    lblUNumberTotal.Text = CStr(intLetterU)
                ElseIf chrCurrentCharacter = "CH" Then
                    intLetterCH += 1
                    lblCHNumberTotal.Text = CStr(intLetterCH)
                ElseIf chrCurrentCharacter = " " Then
                    intWords += 1
                    lblTotalNumberWords.Text = CStr(intWords)
                End If

            End If

        Next

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you're asking for:

```
  Dim strLetterToFind  As String

        strLetterToFind = ComboBox1.SelectedItem


        Try
            lblTotalNumberWords.Text =  Regex.Matches(TextBox1.Text,Regex.Escape(strlettertofind)).Count.ToString)
        Catch ex As Exception
            lblTotalNumberWords.Text = "Please select a option in the combo box"
        End Try
```

You'll need to import System.Text.RegularExpressions for it to work.

Let me know if you have any problems with this

Comment: Thanks for you time, but I need to keep the code close to what I have.  It took a bit more, but I got it.  Again, thanks for your time.